# Conditions on probability measure that generates non-void random polytope

Tags: pr.probability, convex-polytopes, convexity

Let $C$ be a non-void compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\nu$ a probability measure on $C$. Then under what conditions on $C$ and $\nu$, the following statement is true: If $X_1,\cdots,X_{d+1}$ are i.i.d. generated by the law $\nu$, then with probability one, $\mathrm{conv}(X_1,\cdots,X_{d+1})$ has non-void interior?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a generalization of "no atoms" to "no strict subspace has positive measure"?